# Breathing during abs workout (Weider 6)

Tags: workout, abdominals, breathing

I'm following a series of daily abs exercises to gain a "6 pack" (is it called this way?).

As one can see at [Weider's Six page](http://weidersix.com/) all exercises include pulling up legs, chest and face, holding the position for 3 seconds, and then rest for a second.

I found these workouts effective as I gained some abs, however, even if I make it through every workout, I really can't breathe well and always find myself in need of oxygen.

When doing normal sit ups or any "up-down" excercise, I can sync my breathe with the movement, knowing when my diaphragm is contracted or relaxed.

**How do I breathe during Weider 6 exercises?**

Answer (score 3):

These exercises are variations of the hollow body hold, which is quite a common exercise for gymnasts in order to perfect their handstand.

As this an intense core exercise, it is always going to be especially hard to breath due to the abs being held in contraction.

However, I personally do these types of exercises and find that quick forceful exhaling and slow inhaling seems to work best, in order to keep a natural rhythm going.

Answer (score 1):

Usually during abs workout you would breathe-out at the end of the contraction (and not during the phase of contraction) and slowly breathe-in the way back (muscle relaxing phase). Also, please keep in mind to tighten the muscle during the contraction. I am practising this currently and could see improvement.

e.g. During ab crunches, breathe-out at the end of the crunch and breathe-in way back while you lie back.

Hope this helps.